# Different determinants on 2 different computers

Tags: matrix, windows, mac-os-x

Is there any way to force `Det` to do itself in a certain way?

I've been running the same notebook on 2 differents computer, one MacOSX Lion and one W7 (both 32bit) with *Mathematica 8.0.0.0* on the two of them, and we don't get the same `Det` expression and `Solve[Det[F[x]]==0,x]` doesn't give the same solutions either.

How to know which one says the truth? How could we calculate the `Det` in order the have the same solutions on both computers?
Note: as its the same nb the matrices (26*26) are exactly the same.

Comment: Please post the matrices.  Are these symbolic matrices? Numerical ones?  Do they have exact or inexact numbers?  If inexact, machine precision or arbitrary precision?  There are so many different variables that it'll be impossible to say anything unless you either post the matrix, or even better: post a small program to generate the matrix (the definition of `F`, I assume).

Comment: I think you posted a now deleted Q with numerically unstable functions

Comment: Now its "better" -> more stable. They are completely inexact, calculated before with some long lines so all I can give is the complete nb (there is no way to generate the matrices in a few lines). Here is the nb: http://depositfiles.com/files/sq0miedz8 Note the last Outputs: the answer it gives me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the relevant lines

`PulsProp[\[Omega]_, N0_] = Simplify[Det[matK - (\[Omega]^2)*matM]]`

and

`test = Solve[PulsProp[\[Omega], 5000] == 0 && \[Omega] > 0, \[Omega]]`?

If yes, you might get a much more stable behavior by noting that $\omega^2$ are in fact the generalized eigenvalues

`\[Omega]2 = Eigenvalues[{matK, matM}]`

where you can select the positive ones

`test = (\[Omega] -> #) /@ Sqrt@Select[\[Omega]2, PositiveQ]`.

Comment: `Simplify[Det[matK - (\[Omega]^2)*matM]]` is the matter. The two lines you are talking about are relevant in order to calculate the roots of the det, which is supposed to give frequencies (omega/2Pi). Thus the matM is not "perfectly" diagonal, I don't remember my math courses very well then I can't judge if the eigenvalues gives the wanted solutions. What makes me doubt is that the `Plot[Det[]==0,..]` gives me Omega = 3,xxxx, which is not given by your solutions. Which one is good?

Comment: I think you got it right, I've tried with `nmax=1` on the nb & it find the same result with `Det==0` & with `Eigenvalues[]`. But I still don't get what does Eigenvalues[{matK,matM}] do (!), and then why can we tell that the Eigenvalues, calculated god knows how, give me the right solutions? Because matM is bi-diagonal?

Comment: @Öskå: Eigenvalues[{A,B}] solves the problem $\det(A - \lambda B)=0$ for $\lambda$; however in a numerically stable version unlike writing down the polynomial equation for $\lambda$ and then solving it...

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solves everything! :)